# Rewrite language URI path to other path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, request, uri, locale

I have a little trouble to implement a htaccess rewrite rule. I just need rewrite any language ID passed as URI to other URI inside my MVC framework.

Basically, when someone write something like:

> http://www.example.com/en-us or http://www.example.com/pt-br

The URL to rewrite must be:

> http://www.example.com/locale/to/en-us and http://www.example.com/locale/to/pt-br

I already try to implement something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(pt-br|en-us)
RewriteRule (.*) /locale/to/$1
```

But doesn't work, I can't get a rewrite using this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution to fix my question is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/((pt-br|en|en-us).*)
RewriteRule (.*) /locale/to/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Using this rule, the rewrite will work as espected.